# Proof of Interpolation Inequality in $L^p$ Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, interpolation

I am looking for a proof of the following interpolation inequality:

$ ||u||_{p} \leq ||u||^{N(p-1)/(2+N(p-1))}_{pN/(N-2)} ||u||_{1}^{2/(2+ N(p-1))} $

Where $||\cdot||_{p} = ||\cdot||_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}$. If anyone could provide a proof, or even a source that I could read myself, I would greatly apppreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: where did this inequality appear? Do you even know that it is true?

Comment: Do you have any relation between$p$ and $N$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows from the well-known inequality (which is itself a simple consequence of Hölder's inequality): Let $u \in L^p \cap L^q$ for some $p,q \in [1,\infty]$.
For $\lambda \in [0,1]$ we define $r \in [1,\infty]$ via
$$
\frac1r = \lambda \, \frac1p + (1-\lambda) \, \frac1q,$$
i.e. we take a convex combination of the reciprocals.
Then,
$$
\|u\|_r \le \|u\|_p^\lambda \, \|u\|_q^{1-\lambda}.$$